# How to auto end/destroy an existing connected putty session (any telnet or ssh) for a user, if permission has been modified

Tags: linux, aix

How to auto end/destroy an existing connected putty session (any telnet or ssh) for a user, if 'root' has changed the permission for that user to not access any cmd?

Comment: I know that, if I will create/establish a new connection then all new permissions will be in active mode & the user will not get the privilege to execute any cmd. But I want these permissions to be in active mode in opened other terminals (which were opened at the time we had modified the permission using root user).

Comment: Instead of fixing a small typo, if you guys could provide me any suggestion or answer, then I would appreciate this.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not clear of the situation.  Are you asking how a sys admin could kill existing connections?

```
ps -fu joebob | awk '{print $2}' | xargs kill -9
```

or you could restrict it to only processes with a controlling terminal with a little bit of more programming (and not kill joebob's process that are in the background).

Or is this from the perspective of the uesr himself?  `exit` is an internal shell command that will terminate the shell.  Most shells also have an auto log out feature where it logs out after so many seconds of inactivity.

So far, it seems too contrived of a situation.  What are you really trying to do?